# Isolation of directives with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular. I created a small directive where the user can input a timestamp and add/substract 1 day. The directive needs to be isolated so that it can appear multiple times in my application.

This is the part where I initialize my dates:

```
$scope.dateFrom = {
    label : 'Date From',
    date : mii.utils.date.dateToIntDate(start)
}
$scope.dateUntil = {
    label : 'Date Until',
    date : mii.utils.date.dateToIntDate(end)
}
```

In the HTML of my view I create 2 instances of my directive:

```
<date-input date="dateFrom"></date-input>

<date-input date="dateUntil"></date-input>
```

The result looks like the below image. Two seperate input fields, each has its own label and default value. So far the isolation seems to be working.

[image: dates]

The problem is however, when I click the plus sign of `Date From`, it will add a day to the value of `Date Until`. When I look in the debugger on function `_addDays` I see that `$scope.dateInfo` is indeed pointing to the dateUntil object even though I am interacting with date From. What am I missing?

**date.html**

```
<div id="date-input">
    <span>
        <img src="assets/img/minus.png" class="icon left" ng-click="yesterday()"/>
        {{dateInfo.label}}
        <img src="assets/img/add.png" class="icon right" ng-click="tomorrow()"/>
    </span>
    <input ng-model="dateInfo.date" class="center"/>
</div>
```

**dateController.js**

```
app.directive("dateInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",

        templateUrl : "app/shared/dateInput/date.html",

        scope : {
           dateInfo : "=date"
        },

        link : function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.yesterday = function(){
                _addDays(-1);
            };

            $scope.tomorrow = function(){
                _addDays(1);
            }

            _addDays = function(days){

                var d = mii.utils.date.intDateToDate($scope.dateInfo.date);
                var newD = new Date(d);
                newD.setDate(d.getDate()+days);
                $scope.dateInfo.date = mii.utils.date.dateToIntDate(newD);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've reconstructed your example as a jsfiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/aqewsu40/1/).  I don't have access to some of your libraries, so I've replaced your date time library with moment.js.  But you should get the gist of it.  This example works, so perhaps you can work backwards and see what you may have done differently.  Good luck!

Comment: Never mind... I discovered the issue.  I posted it as an answer, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, all you need to do is prepend `var` to the function definition:

```
var _addDays = function(days){
```

It was a simple oversight -- Because it didn't specifically state its scope, `_addDays` is interpreted as a global variable.  This means that the second time the function is declared, it clobbers the definition of the first.  Even though the function body looks the same, the closure is different in each context.

Comment: Good catch. One could also turn on strict mode to prevent the error in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You're two way binding the `dateInfo` property to the parent scope (in your case, the parent scope is probably the controller scope).  You need to isolate this property to its own child scope after it inherits its initial value from `$scope.date` from the controller.  You can do this with one way data binding

```
    scope : {
       dateInfo : "@date"
    },
```

Notice the `=` has been changed to `@`

This allows `dateInfo` to inherit its initial value from `$scope.date` in your controller.  But once that value is inherited, any changes made to the child scope within the directive itself will not bubble up to `$scope.date` in the controller scope.  You'll then have two child scopes, each with a separate `dateInfo` property that does not corrupt the other.

Comment: Thanks! However when I change this, the dateInfo seems to be empty. The label and default date are not displayed anymore.

Comment: This is incorrect.  While you have correctly pointed out that "=" does make the binding two-way, the OP has specified two separate variables in the directive instances.  In fact, without such a binding, the information is lost to the controller.